# Is Entity Framework suitable for large amount of entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, software-design

Suppose you would develop a big enterprise application with complex business logic and over 100 entities where each of them has 15 properties.

Would you say that Entity Framework is suitable in this case. Or will it cause too much headaches?

Yes I know this question is opinion based. But that is exactly what I want, the opinion of the developers who have been working with big projects.

Comment: *Why* do you think the number of different entity types would cause any trouble?

Comment: I don't have firsthand experience with EF, but I have had some feedback suggesting that schema changes start to become slow as the number of entities grow closer to 100 or beyond. It just takes too long for the developer machine to find out all the schema changes and generate scripts for that. But this is strictly limited to code-first approach.

Comment: You could use different dbContext by feature etc..., if you think the number of entities by DbContext is too large. For read only, like repport etc you could disable lazyloading, tracking, for optimize performance

Comment: Easy enough to find out...  You don't need 'opinions', write a mock-up. Can tell you much more about your exact situation.

Comment: You can't just write "I know this is opinion based but that's what I want, opinions" and make the question be on topic.....

Comment: @KirkWoll  i read this article http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/why-i-do-not-recommend-any-more-entity-framework-as-you-orm . i just want to know if there are other expericened developers who share the same thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

We use EF with a fairly large database, well over 100 entities, many of them with a lot more than 15 properties.

Any ORM is going to be slower than raw SQL, but you have to balance the benefits. If you find performance is an issue, you can address specific areas and optimise them. For example, if you have an entity with a lot of properties, and you query it like this...

```
var jim = ctx.MyEntities;
```

...you may see performance suffer as the number of entries in the table grows. If you modify your query to do this...

```
var jim = ctx.MyEntities
             .Select(j => new{
               Jim1 = j.Jim1,
               // other properties as needed
             });
```

...and only pull out the properties you actually need, you'll find it a lot faster.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answere. Do you use a different persistence model and map them to the domain model or do you use the persistence model as  your domain model ?

Comment: @Lahmacun Depends on the case, but generally we find that the persistence model maps well to the domain model, albeit with minor tweaks. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Like anything, it's fine provided you use it appropriately.

Personally I have not hit any scale problems while using it for OLTP where it makes for great savings in development time and quality, albeit at the expense of some relatively minor inefficiencies.

Where it has let me down is bulk/batch processes, reporting and other large aggregations, even when the resulting rows can be small. In these cases it's well worth stepping out of pure EF and adding some views or stored procedures. These can then be used through EF with the typical benefits.

Keep an open mind and play to its strengths, be flexible and you should be ok.